# With the last G-WAN 7.12.2 where is the 32-bit x86 version?

Tags: x86, 32-bit, g-wan

I'm running different 8-10 year old machines (both Intel and AMD with dual core cpu) on native Ubuntu 32-bit but with only 2 Gb of RAM (today DDR and DDR1 are rare and expensive).

With such low end systems, using Ubuntu 64-bit isn't very efficient.

So, did the G-WAN team drop G-WAN 32-bit (it's not anymore available on the download page and there is nothing in the aged 5.x timeline page either) and if yes, why?

TIA.

Answer (score 0):

The 32-bit Linux platform (kernel, LIBC) apparently receives less care than the 64-bit version and is increasingly causing incompatibility issues.

In addition, 32-bit Linux is less and less deployed - at least for server applications (a mere 0.001% of the G-WAN downloads).

That's why it has been removed.

Fnux is invited to ask G-WAN questions on stackoverflow where it visibly gets timely responses.

Comment: Thank you Gil for your interesting answer. It may be nice to notify on your download page the 32 bit users that you have drop the G-WAN 32-bit release in the same way you do for the Windows release.

Answer (score 0):

The new [G-WAN_full-install](http://www.as2.com/linux/tools/G-WAN_full-install.tar.bz2) bash script is now available (February 21, 2016) and helps you to install not only the latest G-WAN version (7.12.6) but also all the packets and dependencies to play with the 15 supported programming languages as well as more than 90 servlet samples.

This v10m version do not run on Ubuntu non LTS releases (e.g. 15.10) nor any Linux 32-bit distributions since Trustleap stopped to support its own G-WAN 32-bit flavor without notice early this year (2016).

Feel free to contact me by e-mail (fnux.fl@gmail.com) for any problem using this script.

All the best.